# iPhone app enterprise distribution by OTA

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

We are implementing OTA for one of our Enterprise application. We have two servers:

1. Server 1 (has SSL certificate & plist file & not connected to internet)
2. Server 2 (has the ipa and the index.html)

While installing the app only on **iOS 8 it don't install** and give error "Cannot install the app". But if we enable the Server1 internet access then its able to download the ipa file without any issues. We are using Xcode 7.

**[EDIT]**

Console logs from iPad which don't install

```
itunesstored[81] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing placeholder for com.xxxx.xxxx.prod
installd[36] <Notice>: 0x341000 -[MIClientConnection _doBackgroundInstallationForPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.itunesstored/AppPlaceholders/-8484403080815861275.app" type Placeholder requested by itunesstored (pid 81)
installd[36] <Notice>: 0x341000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=com.xxxx.xxxx.prod; Version=1.0, ShortVersion=(null)>
installd[36] <Notice>: 0x341000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:withError:]: Made container live for com.xxxx.xxxx.prod at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A5B9C69F-A609-4EED-A911-DDE2F0B89611
installd[36] <Notice>: 0x341000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:withError:]: Made container live for com.xxxx.xxxx.prod at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/40830C31-35EC-4732-B9A0-24A7D04322BC
installd[36] <Notice>: 0x341000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Staging: 0.02s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 0.24s; Overall: 0.27s
itunesstored[81] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:<LSApplicationProxy: 0x1568e270> com.xxxx.xxxx.prod (Placeholder) withPhase:3
itunesstored[81] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.xxxx.xxxx.prod.InstallingPlaceholder - <NSProgress: 0x15591d70> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   called, removing progress from cache
itunesstored[81] <Warning>: LaunchServices: updating placeholder for com.xxxx.xxxx.prod with icons
installd[36] <Notice>: 0x3c3000 -[MIClientConnection _doBackgroundInstallationForPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.itunesstored/AppPlaceholders/-8484403080815861275.app" type Placeholder requested by itunesstored (pid 81)
installd[36] <Notice>: 0x3c3000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=com.xxxx.xxxx.prod; Version=1.0, ShortVersion=(null)>
installd[36] <Notice>: 0x3c3000 -[MIInstallableBundle _refreshUUIDForContainer:withError:]: Data container for com.xxxx.xxxx.prod is now at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AA9B9100-AF0E-4B33-BA4B-DA2F2395C3A0
 installd[36] <Notice>: 0x3c3000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:withError:]: Made container live for com.xxxx.xxxx.prod at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/58E2E2A7-A65F-43A0-8F7D-CF24A7F7414F
installd[36] <Notice>: 0x3c3000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Staging: 0.15s; Waiting: 0.01s; Installation: 0.68s; Overall: 0.85s
 itunesstored[81] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:<LSApplicationProxy: 0x15679570> com.xxxx.xxxx.prod (Placeholder) withPhase:3
itunesstored[81] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.xxxx.xxxx.prod.InstallingPlaceholder - <NSProgress: 0x15679c70> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   called, removing progress from cache
itunesstored[81] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:<LSApplicationProxy: 0x155850b0> com.xxxx.xxxx.prod (Placeholder) withPhase:0
lsd[72] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: 0x17e304e0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   to 3
lsd[72] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: 0x17e304e0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   to 0
```

Console logs from iPad which install

```
installd[36] <Notice>: 0x1b95000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=com.xxxx.xxxx.prod; Version=1.0, ShortVersion=2.4>
profiled[168] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Provisioning profiles changed
installd[36] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
lockdownd[26] <Error>: Could not set socket option SO_OPPORTUNISTIC: Invalid argument
installd[36] <Notice>: 0x1b95000 -[MIInstallableBundle _refreshUUIDForContainer:withError:]: Data container for com.xxxx.xxxx.prod is now at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B8DEEFE3-9137-44F7-88C0-C5B587C5ED4B
installd[36] <Notice>: 0x1b95000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:withError:]: Made container live for com.xxxx.xxxx.prod at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/F6A1A1C3-7E3E-488E-AC15-206749F145AC
installd[36] <Notice>: 0x1b95000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Staging: 4.86s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 2.30s; Overall: 7.17s
lsd[154] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating identifier store
 itunesstored[155] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.xxxx.xxxx.prod.Installing - <NSProgress: 0x145794c0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 100 of 100   called, removing progress from cache
lsd[154] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installation ended for app com.xxxx.xxxx.prod
 itunesstored[155] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.xxxx.xxxx.prod.Loading - <NSProgress: 0x14587450> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 1 of 1   called, removing progress from cache
```

Comment: Ouch. Can you monitor Server1's traffic to see what it needs?

Comment: Actually i tried to do that from the logs from the iPad. It fails at a certain point while getting the provisioning profile. But it passes the check on the iOS 9 and iOS 7 for the same ipa. I can share more info if you know how to read them :).

Comment: Yes, please share the info!

Comment: @RhythmicFistman i have just edited the question. Sorry for delay reply